# Implementation of List<T> in C#?

Tags: c#, list, implementation

First I'm sorry for my bad English, then my question;

I know that there are many questions like this one, in here, but I didn't find a straight answer. Is `List<T>` implemented using some sort of "linked list" mechanism? Or it is just an over-engineered array?

I'm interested in performance issues of lists, like sorting, inserting and deleting items. E.g. for insertion action, 'linked list' just defines some new connections, but array needs to shift its values. What about list?

Comment: It's an array. In F# they use the name [`ResizeArray<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx) for the same ``List`1[T]`` type.

Comment: The source code for `List<T>` is available; search for "Microsoft shared source initiative" and you'll find it. Then you can answer questions like this yourself.  (To answer your question: `List<T>` is implemented as an array; when the array is full a new array of twice the size is allocated and filled in from the old array.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, List<> is an array.  And yes, Insert() is an O(n) operation.

It is important that it works that way, modern processors are *very* dependent on their caches.  The RAM in your machine is *very* slow, much slower than the processor.  The caches make sequential access to memory fast.  Which is the opposite of what a LinkedList<> does.  A single cache miss costs hundreds of cpu cycles.  Do note another significant disadvantage of LinkedList<>, indexing it costs O(n) unless you can index sequentially.  It is always O(1) for List.

These are but rough guidelines, nobody can advice you to replace your List with a LinkedList.  Only a profiler can do that.

Comment: Thank you Hans, and you're right. I'll stick to my List<>, because my array size will not exceed than 5000-10000.

Comment: Also I set up a small test with "inserting" a value into a list and into an array (n=100M). In one run, array was slightly faster, but within a loop with 25 cycles, list won the average run-time with significant difference. When I increased n to 110M, list threw overflow exception on my machine, but array did not.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it is just an over-engineered array. For Linked List you need `LinkedList<T>`. For more on `LinkedList<T>` read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I would consider `List<T>` an over-engineered array more than a "linked list".

As for performance, since `List<T>` is not inherently sorted, then the performance is dependent upon the sorting algorithm (bubble sort is extremely slow as every item needs to checked).

Inserting and deleting items into a `List<T>` is quite simple and performance can be improved for inserting items by using `List<T>.Add()` vs. `List<T>.Insert()`, as `.Add()` will add it to the end of the list.

For a thorough treatment of the performance and general use cases for various .NET collection types, then read [C#/.NET Fundamentals: Choosing the Right Collection Class](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2011/06/16/c.net-fundamentals-choosing-the-right-collection-class.aspx)

Comment: Great link you've provided!

Comment: Thank you for the link Karl. That was really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No, List is not an linked list and its just a convenient strongly typed array. I would not call it over engineered array, but its one of the best features introduced from C# 2.0. If performance with generic list is a concern they can be optmized based on use cases but just inserting does not take much time even in a huge list.